# How do I remove nitrogen back to Ubuntu's default wallpaper manager?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, desktop-background

I was using nitrogen when I using openbox, but now I'm trying to stop it from setting the wallpaper so I can use the Ubuntu default (i.e via the System Settings panel).

What I've done so far:

- `sudo apt-get remove nitrogen`
- Removed nitrogen configs at `~/.config/nitrogen/`
- Checked to make sure that `draw_background` in `/desktop/gnome/background` was checked

So far it still doesn't work. I can't right-click on the desktop, so I'm guessing that I've missed something to get Nautilus back to drawing icons on the screen. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to enable icons on the desktop in order to solve it. This seemed like the easiest process:

- Install Gnome Tweak Tools: `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`
- Check the option Desktop -> Icons on Desktop

Answer (score 0):

Flow this:

Uninstall just nitrogen:

```
sudo apt-get remove nitrogen
```

This will remove just the nitrogen package itself.

Uninstall nitrogen and its dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove nitrogen
```

This will remove the nitrogen package and any other dependant packages which are no longer needed.

[Read this.](http://www.installion.co.uk/ubuntu/precise/universe/n/nitrogen/uninstall.html)

Comment: Just tried. No luck so far.

Comment: @jonalmeida check active task, are see the nitrogen?

Comment: Nope, there isn't any nitrogen running. I think it's a configuration issue, but I can't seem to find it..

Comment: Check the `desktop perefernces` go to third tab active `show menu provided...` .

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you said.

Comment: read it http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1243914.html

Comment: See my above answer, I found the solution to the problem and I've posted it there.

Thanks for all your help though :)